# Issue on Reading .txt inside a Zipped File by PHP

Tags: php

I have a simple `test.txt` file inside a zipped file called `test.zip`. The test.txt file only contains a string `Hello@2015`. Now I need to read the file by PHP like

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('test.zip#test.txt', 'r'); 
$result = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $result .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
echo $result;
```

but I am getting this warnings
Warning: fopen(test.zip#test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\ZipRead\index.php on line 2

Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\ZipRead\index.php on line 4

Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\ZipRead\index.php on line 4

can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I followed the same code from there but I am not getting the result!

Comment: Check the full path of your "test.zip" file. Are you sure it is in the folder "c:\wamp\www\zipread"?

Comment: @Suffi : but you are not showing the same code `fopen('test.zip#test.txt', 'r'); ` should read `fopen('zip://test.zip#test.txt', 'r'); `. If this did not work what was the error and why did you changed it that way ?